# Inserting lots of rows that only have a single value change into table with lots of column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table I need to insert about 260 rows into, the data will be exactly the same EXCEPT for the value of a single column "project". If this was a small table I would just write it all out using a `UNIN ALL` but the problem is there are 66 total columns in the table and that is a LOT of repetitive typing. Is there a method of inserting nearly identical info without having to repeat it all like this? If it makes any difference it is on an MS SQL 2008 R2 server.

Comment: Add the `project` column to the table, do the insert, then drop the `project` column?

Comment: the `project` column already exists and contains data for everything else. I am simply adding new rows to an existing table.

Comment: @Matthew - So the data you wish to insert does not have the `project` column/data - but the target table does?

Comment: Can you give us an example... You need not write down all 66 though...

Comment: @Matthew - how about breaking it into two step first insert all the new rows.  And then update the single column.   In SQL Server management studio you can right-click a table in the object explorer and select "Script Table As...Insert To" from the context menu.  This will give you a template for an insert with all the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding your requirements correctly, something like this could perhaps work with a subquery building the `project` values:

```
insert into yourtable 
select 1, 'Another Value', ..., t.project
from (select 1 as project union all select 2 ... select 260) t
```

Depending on your table structure, you may need to supply the column names.